# Lotus Notes - check if database is Out of Service (without using Admin client)

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there any way to check if a database replica is "out of service" on a particular server without using the admin client (using either the Notes client or designer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there's a property called `IsInService` in the `NotesDatabase` Lotus Script object.

[NotesDatabase.IsInService documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDATABASE_CLASS.html)